# Threading causes race condition

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition, monitor

[image: a threading question]

I originally assumed the correct answer for this question is A because m2 can be partially used and call statement C while statementB is called because the two locks, "a" and "b" don't protect one another if "b" doesn't exist in the first m1.

C I think is wrong because wouldn't a synchronized method mean using the class itself as a lock, so that way nothing could enter the class if m2 was being used if it was synchronized?

Now I'm wondering if my assumption I made for C was correct. Because though it's using itself as a lock, m1 is using b as a lock to protect statementB. This means there are two monitors, ("B" and "this"), thus allowing for a clash making C the correct answer? But I'm also pretty sure A is correct as well.

Let me know if you see any flaw in my reasoning or if you know the correct answer and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with A.  It removes the mutual exclusion of the operations **statementB;** and **statementC;** possibly violating it in a way that breaks things.

B and D are unobservable reductions in lock granularity that may degrade performance.

C is an observable change in lock granularity that could expose problematic locking by other clients.  C is not a significant change in the behaviour of *this* code.  It's a bit of a trick question.  It could wind up being significant in the client code, but isn't locally significant.  It preserves all of the origin local guarantees of mutual exclusion of the statements.

A is definitely the answer.

Comment: can you talk more on why C is not the correct answer by addressing why I thought it was correct?

Comment: @user2977578 thow an upvote on that if you get a chance ;)